# RubyMine bundle/bundler configuration error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, rubymine

I am on windows and using RubyMine to develop an app.  My 2-year old was found banging on the keyboard when I had stepped away for a sec.  She did something to the environment that I can't figure out.  I'm getting the following error when I try to run `bundle install` or `bundle update`:

```
C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin/bundle update
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load': cannot load such file -- C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.4.0.rc.1/bin/bundle (LoadError)
from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

My gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.11'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'wicked'  #For handling *.pdf documents, use wicked_pdf
gem 'public_activity'
gem 'thin'
gem 'strong_parameters'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
  # gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'sqlite3'
  gem 'autotest'
  gem 'autotest-rails-pure'

end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'

end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'

end
```

`bcrypt-ruby` is set to  `gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'` to handle another error (duplicate version load error).

My gem environment is this:

```
RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.24
RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-22 patchlevel 392) [i386-mingw32]
INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin
RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  ruby
  x86-mingw32
GEM PATHS:
   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
   C:/Documents and Settings/Me/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
GEM CONFIGURATION:
   :update_sources => true
   :verbose => true
   :benchmark => false
   :backtrace => false
   :bulk_threshold => 1000
REMOTE SOURCES:
   http://rubygems.org/
----------------------
IDE: JetBrains RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1, build #RM-129.861
OS: Windows XP 5.1[x86]
Java: 1.7.0_10-b18
RubyMine SDK Environment:
Sdk: ruby-1.9.3-p392
Sdk Version: ver.1.9.3p392 p392
Ruby Interpreter: C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe
RVM Sdk: no
Sdk Language Level: 1.9
Sdk Load Path:
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/i386-msvcrt
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/i386-msvcrt
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32
     C:/Program Files/RubyMine 5.4.3.2.1/rubystubs193
Sdk Gem paths: 
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems
     C:/Documents and Settings/Kraig/.gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems
     C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bundler/gems
Gems used for 'ballast':
     diff-lcs (1.2.4)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/diff-lcs-1.2.4
     rack-test (0.6.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-test-0.6.2
     coffee-rails (3.2.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2
     erubis (2.7.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/erubis-2.7.0
     uglifier (2.2.1)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.2.1
     actionmailer (3.2.11)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionmailer-3.2.11
     pg (0.17.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.17.0-x86-mingw32
     arel (3.0.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/arel-3.0.2
     builder (3.0.4)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/builder-3.0.4
     autotest-rails-pure (4.1.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/autotest-rails-pure-4.1.2
     public_activity (1.4.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/public_activity-1.4.0
     thin (1.5.1)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.5.1
     rails (3.2.11)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-3.2.11
     eventmachine (1.0.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3-x86-mingw32
     paperclip (3.5.1)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/paperclip-3.5.1
     mail (2.4.4)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mail-2.4.4
     json (1.8.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.8.0
     daemons (1.1.9)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.9
     climate_control (0.0.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/climate_control-0.0.3
     activesupport (3.2.11)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.11
     journey (1.0.4)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/journey-1.0.4
     rake (10.1.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.1.0
     coffee-script (2.2.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-2.2.0
     jquery-rails (3.0.4)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4
     rdoc (3.12.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rdoc-3.12.2
     railties (3.2.11)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.11
     rspec-core (2.14.5)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.5
     multi_json (1.8.1)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.8.1
     ZenTest (4.8.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ZenTest-4.8.3
     rspec-mocks (2.14.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-mocks-2.14.3
     execjs (2.0.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.0.2
     thor (0.18.1)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1
     sprockets (2.2.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.2.2
     wicked (1.0.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/wicked-1.0.0
     strong_parameters (0.2.1)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/strong_parameters-0.2.1
     polyglot (0.3.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/polyglot-0.3.3
     tilt (1.4.1)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.4.1
     annotate (2.5.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/annotate-2.5.0
     activeresource (3.2.11)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activeresource-3.2.11
     autotest (4.4.6)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/autotest-4.4.6
     bcrypt-ruby (3.1.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.1.2-x86-mingw32
     mime-types (1.25)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mime-types-1.25
     i18n (0.6.5)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/i18n-0.6.5
     activerecord (3.2.11)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.11
     rack-ssl (1.3.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-ssl-1.3.3
     rspec-rails (2.14.0)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.14.0
     activemodel (3.2.11)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.2.11
     sass-rails (3.2.6)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-rails-3.2.6
     rack (1.4.5)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.5
     treetop (1.4.15)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/treetop-1.4.15
     sass (3.2.12)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sass-3.2.12
     rack-cache (1.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-cache-1.2
     sqlite3 (1.3.8)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/sqlite3-1.3.8-x86-mingw32
     hike (1.2.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/hike-1.2.3
     tzinfo (0.3.37)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tzinfo-0.3.37
     actionpack (3.2.11)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.11
     rspec-expectations (2.14.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-expectations-2.14.3
     coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/coffee-script-source-1.6.3
     cocaine (0.5.2)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cocaine-0.5.2
     bundler (1.3.4)
         C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.3.4
```

I have tried to manually update the gem in question, revert back to an older version, etc.  I can't figure out why the error is occuring.  `rails s` won't work until i get this debugged.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Does the file `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.4.0.rc.1/bin/bundle` exist?

Try uninstalling and then reinstalling the bundler gem.

Comment: The bundler should be looking for -v 1.3.4.  Why is it trying to load 1.4.0.rc?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe 1.4.0.rc.1 was installed at some point? Did you try reinstalling? What is in `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/bundle`?